How to address (not ignore) react exhaustive-deps linter rule without causing infinite rerender loop when fetching data
In real life I would probably be using react-query for this, but to solidify my understanding, I am trying to implement basic pagination in a minimal hacker news jobs board clone with useReducer and useEffect alone. The following code works, but results in an exhaustive-deps linter warning:

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'listings'. Either
include it or remove the dependency array.

import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const initialState = {
  page: 1,
  listings: [],
  ids: [],
  initializationStatus: "loading",
};

function jobListingReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "incrementPage":
      return { ...state, page: state.page + 1 };

    case "decrementPage":
      return { ...state, page: state.page - 1 };

    case "getListings":
      return {
        ...state,
        initializationStatus: "fulfilled",
        ids: action.payload.ids,
        listings: action.payload.listings,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

async function fetchIds() {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json"
  );
  return await response.json();
}

async function fetchListings(ids) {
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    ids.map((id) => fetch(
      `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`
    ))
  );

  return await Promise.all(
    responses.map((response) => response.json())
  );
}

const LISTINGS_PER_PAGE = 6;

export default function JobBoard2() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(jobListingReducer, initialState);
  const { ids, listings, initializationStatus, page } = state;

  const startIndexForDisplayedListings = (page - 1) * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const endIndexForDisplayedListings =
    startIndexForDisplayedListings + LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const displayedListings = listings.slice(
    startIndexForDisplayedListings,
    endIndexForDisplayedListings
  );

  const hasMore = ids.length > page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getListings() {
      let idsForListings = ids.length ? ids : await fetchIds();
      const startIndex = page === 1
        ? 0
        : page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE - LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
      const endIndex = LISTINGS_PER_PAGE * page;
      const hasNeededListings = listings.length >= endIndex;
      const newListings = hasNeededListings
        ? []
        : await fetchListings(idsForListings.slice(startIndex, endIndex));

      dispatch({
        type: "getListings",
        payload: {
          ids: idsForListings,
          listings: [...listings, ...newListings],
        },
      });
    }
    getListings();
  }, [page, ids]);

  if (initializationStatus === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {page > 1 && <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrementPage" })}>
          prev page
        </button>
      }
      {hasMore && <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "incrementPage" })}>
          next page
        </button>
      }
      <ul>
        {displayedListings.map((listing) => (
          <li key={listing.id}>{listing.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

But adding listings into the dependency array causes an infinite re-render loop. I've long treated this scenario as an instance where I just disable the warning, but wonder if my mental model for this is wrong and there is actually a valid way to address the linter warning (other than using react-query or some other abstraction that takes care of this under the hood).
Edit: one of the answers so far uses abortController to handle a double-rendering bug it introduces (that is only seen in React.StrictModemode). I am a little skeptical that this is the way to handle. react-query does not use abortController by default, and accomplishing the functionality above with react-query is relatively straightforward:
import {useQueries, useQuery} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import {useState} from "react";

async function fetchIds() {
    const response = await fetch("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json");
    return await response.json();
}

async function fetchListing(id) {
    const response = await fetch(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`);
    return await response.json();
}

const LISTINGS_PER_PAGE = 10;

export default function JobBoard3() {
    const {data: ids, isLoading: isLoadingIds} = useQuery({queryKey: ["ids"], queryFn: fetchIds});
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const startIndex = page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE - LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
    const endIndex = startIndex + LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
    const displayedIds = ids?.slice(startIndex, endIndex) || [];

    const {results: listings, pending: isLoadingListings} = useQueries({
        queries: displayedIds?.map((id) => ({
            queryKey: ["listing", id],
            queryFn: () => fetchListing(id),
            enabled: !!displayedIds.length,
        })),
        combine: (results) => {
            return {
                results: results.map((result) => result.data),
                pending: results.some((result) => result.isPending),
            };
        },
    });

    if (isLoadingIds || isLoadingListings) {
        return <p>Is Loading...</p>;
    }

    const hasMore = ids.length > page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;

    return (
        <>
            {page > 1 && <button onClick={() => setPage(page - 1)}>prev page</button>}
            {hasMore && <button onClick={() => setPage(page + 1)}>next page</button>}
            <ul>
                {listings.map((result) => (
                    <li key={result.id}>{result.title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}


Move the [...listings, ...newListings], logic into your reducer where it belongs, it's what the reducers are for after all, e.g. computing the next state. This is so listings is removed as an external dependency.
Example:
function jobListingReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "incrementPage":
      return { ...state, page: state.page + 1 };

    case "decrementPage":
      return { ...state, page: state.page - 1 };

    case "getListings":
      const { ids, listings } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        initializationStatus: "fulfilled",
        ids,
        listings: [...state.listings, ...listings],
        // or
        // listings: state.listings.concat(...listings),
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function getListings() {
    let idsForListings = ids.length ? ids : await fetchIds();
    const startIndex = page === 1
      ? 0
      : page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE - LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
    const endIndex = LISTINGS_PER_PAGE * page;
    const hasNeededListings = listings.length >= endIndex;
    const newListings = hasNeededListings
      ? []
      : await fetchListings(idsForListings.slice(startIndex, endIndex));

    dispatch({
      type: "getListings",
      payload: {
        ids: idsForListings,
        listings: newListings,
      },
    });
  }
  getListings();
}, [page, ids]);


There's now a bug where the first page of listings is inserted into
state twice, so the first time "next page" is clicked, the same
results show (although that does not occur on subsequent pagination
events).

That sounds like an issue caused using the React.StrictMode component is non-production builds double-mounting/double-useEffect-call, use an AbortController to cancel any in-flight fetch requests so the mount/remount logic works correctly. You might also try computing startIndex, endIndex, and hasNeededListings outside the useEffect callback, referenced as stable dependencies since they are strings/booleans.
I was able to reproduce the problem above and I've tested the following implementation and it seems to work as expected within the StrictMode component.
async function fetchIds(options = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/jobstories.json",
    options,
  );
  return response.json();
}

async function fetchListings(ids = [], options = {}) {
  return Promise.all(
    ids.map((id) =>
      fetch(
        `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`,
        options
      ).then((response) => response.json())
    )
  );
}

const LISTINGS_PER_PAGE = 6;

export default function JobBoard2() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(jobListingReducer, initialState);

  const { ids, listings, initializationStatus, page } = state;

  const startIndexForDisplayedListings = (page - 1) * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const endIndexForDisplayedListings =
    startIndexForDisplayedListings + LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const displayedListings = listings.slice(
    startIndexForDisplayedListings,
    endIndexForDisplayedListings
  );

  const hasMore = ids.length > page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const startIndex = page === 1
    ? 0
    : page * LISTINGS_PER_PAGE - LISTINGS_PER_PAGE;
  const endIndex = LISTINGS_PER_PAGE * page;
  const hasNeededListings = listings.length >= endIndex;

  useEffect(() => {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;

    const getListings = async () => {
      try {
        const idsForListings = ids.length ? ids : await fetchIds({ signal });

        const newListings = hasNeededListings
          ? []
          : await fetchListings(
              idsForListings.slice(startIndex, endIndex),
              { signal }
            );

        dispatch({
          type: "getListings",
          payload: {
            ids: idsForListings,
            listings: newListings
          }
        });
      } catch (error) {
        // catch any thrown exceptions or rejected Promises
      }
    };

    getListings();

    return () => {
      // Abort any in-flight fetch requests
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [ids, startIndex, endIndex, hasNeededListings]);

  if (initializationStatus === "loading") {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      {page > 1 && (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "decrementPage" })}>
          prev page
        </button>
      )}
      {hasMore && (
        <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "incrementPage" })}>
          next page
        </button>
      )}
      <ul>
        {displayedListings.map((listing) => (
          <li key={listing.id}>{listing.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}


Thanks, I think that's a move in the right direction. I still see a linter warning complaining of a missing dependency 'listings.length', and don't see a way to remove that. If I were to use redux, I'd have that logic in a thunk, but not sure what the analog to that is here. Also, there's now a bug where the first page of listings is inserted into state twice, so the first time "next page" is clicked, the same results show (although that does not occur on subsequent pagination events).

@D2024 That sounds like an issue caused using the React.StrictMode component is non-production builds, use an AbortController to cancel any in-flight fetch requests so the mount/remount logic works correctly. You might also try computing hasNeededListings (and anything else maybe) outside the useEffect callback, but this is just pushing dependencies around at this point to make the linter happy. I think you could get the code to where you only need idsForListings, startIndex, and endIndex` as stable dependencies.

@D2024 Ok, what I suggested in my previous comment seems to work as I expected. It looks like it addresses the extra effect running and duplicating some data. Please do take a look again when you can.

I'll mark the question answered because it does address the react eslint rules violation, but am very skeptical about the need for abortController. I added some info and new code to my original question in relation to this. But if this is what it takes to do that, I would likely accept the violation and use my original code. Or better yet, use redux or react-query to handle.

@D2024 You did say you would likely integrate a library but wanted to understand the basics, conceptually. Redux-Toolkit (and their Query module) are great for this sort of task. Once a query for data has been made, and cached, so long as a previous result is cached and not invalidated the cached result is returned to the UI instead of making another network call. React-Query likely works similarly, e.g. avoid making the second fetch to begin with. They both have a lot more going on to manage request tracking and caching results, using an AbortController is just a trivial solution.

@D2024 Welcome, happy to help, by the way. Cheers!
